# How to correctly build a TCP frame decoder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, node-streams

I'm trying to find a simple, modular and idiomatic way of parsing a text based protocol for TCP streams.

Say the protocol looks like this:
`"[begin][length][blah][blah]...[blah][end][begin]...[end][begin]...[end]"`

I'd like to correctly use streams (Transform?) to build a small component which just extracts individual messages (starts with [begin] and ends with [end]). Parsing to higher level data structures is left to other components.

I'm not so concerned about performance right now either so I'd just like to use a simple regex (this protocol is parsable with a regex).

I'm having trouble with a couple of concepts:

1. Since the buffer may have not have a complete message, how do I correctly handle state and leave the partial message alone, to be parsed when more data comes in? Do I have to keep my own buffer or is there a way "put back" the data I didn't use?
2. Since new data may contain several messages, can the `Transform` stream handle multiple messages (like do I call `this.push(data);` multiple times)?

(note that I'm trying to build this frame decoder *outside* of socket connection logic...I imagine it will be a class which extends `stream.Transform` and implement the `read` method)

Comment: have look into `msgpack` or `protobuf`?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix the protocol already exists (called FIX). I'm not creating my own.

Comment: I see , it just looked like that. check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-quickfix it looks well tested. The theory for text based protocol parsing is that if it doesn't use some kind of delimiter it will probably use fixed length messages, either way you still read chunks until you consider the buffer to have the message which in turn is delimited with double nulls or whatever the protocol uses, then you work with it.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix thanks, but I'm trying to write my own parser :). I've already written a couple of them in node and one or two more in java. My goal is to learn to use Node's streams correctly, this parsing stuff, I've done plenty of times :)

Comment: NodeJS streams are not different than in any other protocol, take a look at https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook and find the RFC of the protocol and implement it.